# ui-select2 does not put the wanted value from code

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, ui-select2

I have few selects that looks like that:

```
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <label class="control-label" for="ModelSelect">Model </label>
                    <select ng-disabled="markedDic['make']!=true" class="form-control col-md-2" id="ModelSelect"
                            name="model" ui-select2
                            ng-model="carDetails.model">
                        <option ng-if="!carDetails.model" value="">[SELECT]</option>
                        <option ng-repeat="(model, value) in modelsDic" value="{{ model }}">{{ model}}</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <label class="control-label" for="VolumeSelect">Engine </label>
                    <select ng-disabled="markedDic['model'] != true" class="form-control col-md-2" id="VolumeSelect"
                            name="volume" ui-select2
                            ng-model="carDetails.volume">
                        <option ng-if="!carDetails.volume" value="">[SELECT]</option>
                        <option ng-repeat="(volume, value) in volumesDic" value="{{ volume }}">{{ volume }}</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
```

As you can see, in every select the ng-disabled it dependent on markedDic[] 
and the first option is following the same pattern

```
 <option ng-if="!carDetails.volume" value="">[SELECT]</option>
```

When the form just loads, everything is fine, the default value is [SELECT] and then the rest of the values are the others.
But when I change in my javascript for example

```
carDetails.volume = "";
```

it makes the selected value in the select to be "" but still lets [SELECT] to be an option in the list.
While what I meant was that [SELECT] will be the option that is being showed as the selected value after my change in the js code.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try making `carDetails.volume` value to null will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `ng-if` checking for not null and undefined can solve the problem. Try this because `!""` will return truthy value.

```
ng-if="carDetails.model !== null && "carDetails.model !== undefined"
ng-if="carDetails.volume !== null && "carDetails.volume !== undefined"
```

Comment: It actually work but I didn't understand why, can you explain please?

Comment: I did explain it, It is because when you set the value to empty string `""` not of empty string returns a true value which  we don't want. So instead we are checking for null and undefined.